# Scene doesn't load on button click Godot

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

the sounds plays but the scene doesn't change, I don't know what to do. I'm a beginner Basically it is a plane shop in my game, but the scene doesn't change. Appreciate any help!
This is my code:
`

```
extends Control
onready var default_plane_button = $DefaultPlaneButton
onready var plane_1_button = $BuyPlane1
onready var plane_2_button = $BuyPlane2
onready var plane_3_button = $BuyPlane3
onready var plane_4_button = $BuyPlane4


func _on_BuyPlane1_button_up():
    var read_dictionary = str2var(change_file().get_as_text())
    var new_dictionary = read_dictionary
    if new_dictionary["plane_1_bought"] == true:
        new_dictionary["plane_equipped"] = 1
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_1_button.text = "Equipped"
    elif new_dictionary["coins"] >= 1000:
        global.button_click_sound.play()
        new_dictionary["coins"] -= 1000
        print(new_dictionary)
        new_dictionary["plane_1_bought"] = true
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_1_button.text = "Equip"
    else:
        print("insufficient coins")
        global.no_click_sound.play()
        

func _on_BuyPlane2_button_up():
    var read_dictionary = str2var(change_file().get_as_text())
    var new_dictionary = read_dictionary
    if new_dictionary["plane_2_bought"] == true:
        new_dictionary["plane_equipped"] = 2
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_2_button.text = "Equipped"
    elif new_dictionary["coins"] >= 2000:
        global.button_click_sound.play()
        new_dictionary["coins"] -= 2000
        new_dictionary["plane_2_bought"] = true
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_2_button.text = "Equip"
    else:
        print("insufficient coins")
        global.no_click_sound.play()

func _on_BuyPlane3_button_up():
    var read_dictionary = str2var(change_file().get_as_text())
    var new_dictionary = read_dictionary
    if new_dictionary["plane_3_bought"] == true:
        new_dictionary["plane_equipped"] = 3
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_3_button.text = "Equipped"
    elif new_dictionary["coins"] >= 3000:
        global.button_click_sound.play()    
        new_dictionary["coins"] -= 3000
        new_dictionary["plane_3_bought"] = true
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_3_button.text = "Equip"
    else:
        print("insufficient coins")
        global.no_click_sound.play()

func _on_BuyPlane4_button_up():
    var read_dictionary = str2var(change_file().get_as_text())
    var new_dictionary = read_dictionary
    if new_dictionary["plane_4_bought"] == true:
        new_dictionary["plane_equipped"] = 4
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_4_button.text = "Equipped"
    elif new_dictionary["coins"] >= 4269:
        global.button_click_sound.play()
        new_dictionary["coins"] -= 4269
        new_dictionary["plane_4_bought"] = true
        change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
        change_file().close()
        plane_4_button.text = "Equip"
    else:
        print("insufficient coins")
        global.no_click_sound.play()

func _on_Back_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/Shop.tscn")

func _on_DefaultPlaneButton_button_up():
    global.no_click_sound.play()
    var read_dictionary = str2var(change_file().get_as_text())
    var new_dictionary = read_dictionary
    new_dictionary["plane_equipped"] = 0
    change_file().store_string(var2str(new_dictionary))
    change_file().close()
    change_file().close()
    default_plane_button.text = "Equipped"

func change_file():
    var file = File.new()
    var err = file.open(global.SAVE_FILE, File.READ_WRITE)
    if err == OK:
        return file
        print("open file success")
    else:
        print("error opening file, error: ", err)
func _on_NextButton_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane2.tscn")


func _on_BackButton_pressed():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane1.tscn")


func _on_NextButton1_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane3.tscn")

func _on_NextButton23_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane.tscn")


func _on_BackButton232_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane.tscn")


func _on_BackButton321312_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane2.tscn")


func _on_NextButton23123_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane4.tscn")


func _on_BackButton2212412_button_up():
    global.button_click_sound.play()
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Assets/Room/ShopPlane3.tscn")
```

`

the sounds plays but the scene doesn't change, I don't know what to do. I'm a beginner Basically it is a plane shop in my game, but the scene doesn't change. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in output when the code executes?

Answer (score 0):

I edit my answer. Somewhere there i found a way to change scenes that works for me very well. I dont have the reference anymore (if someone does, please tell), but this is the way:

Add a Global.gd script to autoload (Project->Project settings->Autoload) with this code:

```
extends Node

var current_scene = null

func _ready():
    var root = get_tree().root
    current_scene = root.get_child(root.get_child_count() - 1)

func goto_scene(path, params=null):
    # This function will usually be called from a signal 
    # callback,
    # or some other function in the current scene.
    # Deleting the current scene at this point is
    # a bad idea, because it may still be executing code.
    # This will result in a crash or unexpected behavior.

    # The solution is to defer the load to a later time, when
    # we can be sure that no code from the current scene is 
    # running:

    call_deferred("_deferred_goto_scene", path)


func _deferred_goto_scene(path):
    # It is now safe to remove the current scene
    current_scene.free()

    # Load the new scene.
    var s = ResourceLoader.load(path)

    # Instance the new scene.
    current_scene = s.instance()

    # Add it to the active scene, as child of root.
    get_tree().root.add_child(current_scene)

    # Optionally, to make it compatible with the 
    SceneTree.change_scene() API.
    get_tree().current_scene = current_scene
```

Then, when you want to change scene do this:

```
Global.goto_scene("res://path/yourscene.tscn")?
```